# How to create a shortcut in the launcher with specific enironment variable?

Tags: debian, shortcuts, environment-variables, xfce

I want to start emacs with `LANG` environment variable set to `en_US.UTF-8`, and I don't want to affect other programs.

In terminal, it could be realized using `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 emacs`. Then I created a shortcut in the launcher with this command. But when I clicked on it, an error dialog prompted out saying that:

```
Failed to execute child.
Failed to execute child process "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" (No such file or directory).
```

Why is that? And how to create such a shortcut?

Comment: Here is a link to my `.emacs` setup in a stackoverflow related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20736147/2112489

Comment: Thanks lawlist, but it'S different. I want to set it before emacs' start. This is not an emacs specific question. Sorry that I shouldn't tag it as emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `env` program for the command in the launcher (setting the `Exec` key in the according .desktop file):

> env LANG=en_US.UTF-8 emacs